# Pandas locate minimum of DataFrame matrix: index, col

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get the index and column name of the minimum value in a pandas DataFrame across all rows and all columns.

I've tried .idxmin but this seems to only work when applied on a column. Ideally the function is a one-liner that doesn't require loops. It seems like a very common problem, but I haven't found a solution yet.

My DataFrame:

```
      col0, col1, col2
index0 1     2     3 
index1 2     3     4
index2 5     6     7
```

I'd like to get the index and column for the minimum value across matrix: 1.

so:

```
some_func(df) = (index0,col0)
```

Comment: `df.idxmin(1)` ?

Comment: You can get the min value of the whole dataframe with `df.min().min()` may be someone else can tell us how to get the index & column for that value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.stack().idxmin()

Out[108]: ('index0', 'col0')
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Numpy and `divmod`

```
i, j = divmod(np.argmin(np.ravel(df)), df.shape[1])

(df.index[i], df.columns[j])

('index0', 'col0')
```

Comment: I always like your numpy solution :) +1

Comment: Your's is super slick though (-: